# NameError when using the Python debugger (ipdb)

Tags: python, pdb, ipdb

I'm trying to become more adept at using the debugger, and am following the examples given in http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2005/09/01/debugger.html. I'm currently trying this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ipdb

def test_debugger(some_int):
    print "start some int>>", some_int
    return_int = 10 / some_int
    print "end some_int>>", some_int
    return return_int

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ipdb.run("test_debugger(0)")
```

However, if I run it and try to press `n`, I get a `NameError`:

```
> <string>(1)<module>()

ipdb> n
NameError: "name 'test_debugger' is not defined"
```

As I understand from https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#pdb.run, it should be possible to use the `n(ext)` command to run until the actual bug. Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: is there a difference between `pdb` and `ipdb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs you mention, the explanation links to https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval.

It seems that your call to ipdb.run() does not provide a `globals` or `locals` dict, so `test_debugger` is not defined in the context of `run`.

You can make it work like this:

`ipdb.run("test_debugger(0)", {'test_debugger': test_debugger})`